# card expectations

Tags: probability

Beginning probability question

Imagine a standard card deck where cards have the values 2,3,4,...,11(J),12(Q),13(K),14(A).

The deck is shuffled so that every permutation is equally likely.

I draw cards from the deck,
one at a time without replacement, until I draw the queen of spades (Q), at which
point I stop drawing.

**If T represents the number of cards I draw what is the expected value of T.**

The first card I draw I give it to a member of the audience and from then on, whenever I draw a card with value smaller than the card I gave to the member of the audience, I give it to that member.

**What are the expected max and minimum values of the cards I give?**

**What is the expected number of cards I give?**

What is a good way of defining random variables and thinking about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, each card except the queen of spades has an equal chance to be before or after it.

For the second and third, given the rank $r$ of the first card, how many cards do you give to the audience?  You probably shouldn't have the word "expected" in the second question.  Max will come if you start with an ace, min if you start with a $2$.

Comment: For the 2nd question it does come with the word expected. I believe as in "let G be a random variable that somehow represents the value of the card given. Find its expected value then maximize and minimize it". But I am not sure how to define G (my description is tentative)

Comment: Ok, as I read it now I can see that.  The expected min is easy:  it will be a 2, as you will always give one (if that is the first card) or all four of them (if the first card is higher).

Comment: I understand the point that 2 and ace would be min and max but the reasoning behind it is deterministic. Is there a mathematical proof that if we define a random variable, compute its expected value and then minimize/maximize it we would get 2 and ace? It is not clear to me that the 2 approaches will give the same values. I suspect they wont.

Comment: The ace is not the expected max, as you only give an ace if it is the first card.  You have $\frac 1{13}$ chance that each rank is the max.  The expectation is then the average over that.  2 is always the min, so will be the expected min.

Comment: To find the max if I sum over all card values with probability 1/13 this will not take into account that I dont draw all the cards. I only draw until I get a queen of spades. How to get this bit of information in the expectation calculation?

Comment: For the second and third questions I had assumed you went all the way through the pack.  But I see your reading is correct.  That makes it harder.  So you will only hand out a 2 if one comes before the QS.  This will happen with probability $\frac 45$ as all orders of the four 2's and the QS are equally likely.

Comment: So to find the expected minimum value I have to compute the probability of getting a 2,3,4,...,11 before the QS. Are these all $\frac{4}{5}$? What about dependency of these events?

Comment: You will hand out a 3 if it comes before the QS and the first card was not a 2.  It doesn't matter how many 2's came before the QS.  The expected number of 2's to hand out is 2, as each one is handed out with chance $\frac 12$.  The expected number of 3's to hand out is $2\cdot \frac {12}{13}$ and for each rank the probability drops as $12$ is the number of ranks above or equal to the card in question.

Comment: Makes sense. Can I extend this reasoning to find the expected number of cards given?

Comment: You can.  It would be $2 \frac 1{13} \sum_{i=1}^{13}i=\frac {2\cdot 13 \cdot 14}{13\cdot 2}=14$  But I just realized I missed that queens are special-what do you do if the first card is the QS?  Do you hand out the QS if the first card is Q,K, or A?  That will perturb it a bit.

Comment: If the first card is QS I give it away and stop. If the first card is K or A  I give the QS and then stop. If the first card is Q but not S, I give it away and when I get the QS I keep it for me (do not give it away)

Comment: The probability of handing out a 3 would then be $4/5\times 12/13$?

Comment: That would be the probability of handing out at least one 3, yes.

Comment: the probability of handing a queen would then be $1/52+3/4\times (12/13)^{10}$? Thats because either the QS is the first drawn or one of the other 3 queens is drawn before the QS (with none of the cards below a queen drawn as the first card)

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you will have to check the probability of drawing $1,2,3.....52 \,$cards.

Only one card is drawn when the first card is queen of spades. $2$ cards are drawn when the second card is the queen of spades and so on till the probability of the last card being drawn being the queen of spades.